# Accessing text from property from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableview with the cells and every cell pushes detailViewController. I want to assign text of the cell to a textLabel in detailViewController.

.h class of masterView

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *selectedCellText;
```

.m class of masterView

```
@synthesize selectedCellText = _selectedCellText;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedCellText = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.selectedCellText);
}
```

Here NSLog prints name of the cell

.h of detailViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) listOfTricksViewController *aReference;
```

.m of detailViewController

```
@synthesize aReference = _aReference;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.detailViewName.text = self.aReference.selectedCellText;
     NSLog(@"%@",self.aReference.selectedCellText);
}
```

Here NSLog prints `null`.

Comment: Where are you calling detailViewController in the tableView code?

Comment: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailTrick"]){
        NSString *object = nil;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        object = self.cellObjects[indexPath.row];
    }
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method `prepareForSegue` like this :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailTrick"])
    { 
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)segue.
        NSString *object = nil; 
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 

        // Pass data
        detailViewController.aString = self.cellObjects[indexPath.row]; 
    } 
}
```

You need to call your `DetailViewController` and forward the data to this controller (supposing here you have a `@property` aString in your header of `DetailViewController`)

.h of detailViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;
```

.m of detailViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.detailViewName.text = self.aString;
     NSLog(@"%@",self.aString);
}
```

Comment: prepareForSegue method is in MasterView class

Comment: 2013-10-06 14:18:30.715 trickListApp[308:60b] -[UIStoryboardPushSegue setAString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146b71e0
2013-10-06 14:18:30.719 trickListApp[308:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIStoryboardPushSegue setAString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146b71e0'

Comment: cellObjects is an array of string ? a dictionary ?

Comment: how do you build it ? what kind of object did you add inside ?

Comment: By add button i am adding text

Comment: have you add the property `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *aString;` in your detailViewController.h ?